# Configure Elasticsearch rest high level client with Basic credential provider

Tags: security, authentication, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

This question was asked in the follow-up question to my [this SO answer of how to secure JHLRC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62534007/how-to-hit-secure-elastic-search-through-java-high-level-rest-client) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62534007/how-to-hit-secure-elastic-search-through-java-high-level-rest-client#comment110590496_62534636) comment, where I explained how to send Basic Credential in Elasticsearch JHLRC request but it was not at the client level and was at the request level.

I feel configure at the client level, would avoid repeating the same code again in cases, where you are dealing with only a few users it would be helpful to configure the credentials in the client itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the below steps as mentioned in [this official link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/_basic_authentication.html).

Create `CredentialsProvider` using the `BasicCredentialsProvider`.

```
final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider =
                new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("elastic", "elastic"));
```

Now use the `CredentialsProvider` while building the rest client(JHLRC).

```
RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(
                RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(scannerConfiguration.getElasticsearchConfig().getHost(),
                        scannerConfiguration.getElasticsearchConfig().getPort(),
                        "http")).setHttpClientConfigCallback(new RestClientBuilder.HttpClientConfigCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
                        return httpClientBuilder
                                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
                    }
                }));
```